# The equality of three sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A = \{ \emptyset \}$ , $B = \{ \emptyset , \emptyset\} $ and $C = \{ \emptyset , \{\}\}$ . Is $A = B = C$ right ? I think it's true because we can put $\{\}$ instead of $\emptyset$ and also remove duplicate elements .

Comment: Yep, absolutely

Comment: @Hayden Thanks , do you have any suggestion about questions like this ? Sometimes , they're really complicated .

Comment: Practice makes perfect. With a lot of elementary set theory questions, going back to the definitions is a good approach in general.

Comment: Okay , thanks again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The ultimate issue is notation and convention.

- $A=B$ because, generally, we ignore duplicate elements of sets. So, for instance, $\{1,1,1,1\}=\{1\}$.
- $B=C$ more obviously because both $\emptyset$ and $\{\}$ are notations for the empty set, so they're just representing the same thing in different ways.
- So clearly, $A=B=C$.

---

*Mostly posting this so this question can be finally considered to have an answer and thus be removed from the unanswered queue. Made it Community Wiki since I have nothing much of substance to add.*